# Codeigniter Query binding multiple fields with the same value

Tags: codeigniter

I'm in a situation where I'm doing a MySQL query with Codeigniter and where I have a lot of fields value request which are ALL the same.

Example:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM abc WHERE user_id = ? AND msg_from = ? AND msg_to != ?', [$id, $id, $id]);
```

This has just 3 question marks but the query I'm working on is HUGE and has 19 question marks WHICH ARE ALL THE SAME variable.

So I was trying to figure out how to tell Codeigniter all question marks are pointing to the same variable without having to fill an array with 19 times the same variable.

I thought of a for-loop but I wanted to know if a shortcut exist.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do this with Codeigniters Query Builder pretty easily

Something like that should work:

```
$this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('abc');

$arrFields = array('users_id', 'msg_from', 'msg_to');

foreach($arrFields AS $val)
{
    $this->db->where($val, $id);
}

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Ok but my query has 19 fields because is complex and I will not use built-in CI functions (`db->select`, `db->where` etc) I need to use `db->query()`

Comment: is there any reason for that ? Because i can't imagine one single case where i had problems with the Builder except some really tough aggregatfunctions - nevertheless if you dont want to do this with the querybuilder i guess you've to do this by your own ? ;)